# Confusion over RAID controllers for Dell R620 - what will work?

Tags: raid, dell, dell-perc

I have a (remotely located) R620 server with an H310 PERC controller (Described as "405-1110 : H310 Adapter, low profile", part R1DNH -  What I've got is definitely a PCIE card.

First question - What SAS connector interface is this?  (According to the specs it should be an SFF8078  - but this is relevant to the next part of my question -) [image: Back End of H310 PERC card]

Second Question - When I look at [the specs for the H710](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/Documents/dell-perc-h710-spec-sheet.pdf) it talks about an internal SFF8088 connector - but am I misunderstanding something?  I understood the SFF8088 to be EXTERNAL connectors?   Is this an error on the spec sheet?

Third question: When I search on EBAY and the like for PERC H710 R620, most of the listings are not for the PCI form factor card.   Do I need to use the PCI form factor card in my unit, or can I use the other type shown?

Fourth Question: The Dell Distributor quoted me on an H810 card as a replacement for the H310.   Dells website describes the H810 as an EXTERNAL card - and a more expensive one at that.  Is this card appropriate to replace my H310 ?  Does it give me any benefit over the H710 card - if the H710 card will work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The connectors in your picture are SFF-8087
2. You're correct, SFF-8088 is an external connection. That is a documentation typo. The H710 does in fact have the same SFF-8087 internal connections as the H310.
3. I don't believe those other form factors will work, they appear to have a different connector type - I would play it safe and go with the one that matches the form factor of your existing card though. e.g. Dell part number 0GJKT
4. H810 is an external card, and is not a replacement for the H310. You need an H710.